# HTML purifying in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am writing PHP class which have to remove all `potentially dangerous elements or bogus html tag (such as bad links)` from HTML source.

Usually I would use `HTML Purifier library` or similar library,
but self-written code is required in this project.

There are two conditions:

1. It can not have more than 3kB code
2. it should execute really fast

I wrote something that could do the job: http://pihost.pl/purify.php
but i do not know if it is safe enough to use

**My question is**:
Is there any way to test it properly?
Or maybe someone has quick, small and tested library like this?

Comment: What do you mean by `potentially dangerous elements`?

Comment: javascript, flash and java elements, "bad links"

Comment: Security meme: It's advisable to filter out *undesired* attributes (onClick=), but simply bail with an error message on *malicious* content (img src=javascript). Don't try to cleanse malcontent, just drop it.

Comment: i'd like to but i can't [; that's why i wrote this: http://pihost.pl/purify.php - don't know is it working good tho...

Comment: I would also like to see a set of tests that rigorously attempt to break a purifier script. Good question I think, +1

Comment: To your question of whether your library is safe enough -- no, it's not.  It's a monumental task to write a secure HTML parser.  For example, yours fails to prevent multimedia content and flash as `<img dynsrc="url here" />` is permitted.  You definitely want mature code.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you can't just use HTML Purifier. I can't really imagine any reason that you couldn't; even in commercial projects (like the one I work on) you can still use GPL code, if that's what's putting you off.

Comment: 'Round here we work with the Air Force and government contractors quite frequently--amongst the most picky and nonsensical requirements writers on Earth...and even THEY recently started allowing open source solutions such as Tidy (etc) these days.  Tell your client to call Boeing and ask them why they changed their minds....

Comment: There's gotta be pre-canned test regimens for this kind of thing. However, the best testing (security, etc) is still done by a knowledgeable person, probably even someone with a QA title who basically just tries to break things all day long. There is never a 100% guarantee unless you sanitize it really well according to a white list -- agree with @mario.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to consider -- how does your purifier react to broken/malformed HTML? To combat that situation, I would suggest running it through [PHP tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) first to clean up the HTML, before you purify it.

If you want a series of tests, you can try checking out the [tests](http://htmlpurifier.org/viewvc.cgi/htmlpurifier/trunk/tests/) that HTMLPurifier uses.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a ton of example exploits: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

You could try running those through your purifier and see what comes out the other side.